# add element to predefined xml document

Tags: c#, xml

i'm looking for a way to add an element to an xml document that i have built by serializing a List
of Customers .

**CUSTOMER :**

```
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement("CustomerId")]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DOB")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

**A list of CUSTOMERS ( empty when the xml is created )**

```
private void CreateXml(string path)
{
        File.Create(path).Close();
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, customers);
        textWriter.Close();
}
```

how can i now add a new Customer element to the xml file with out having to write allot of 
DOM style code ?

**EDIT :**

i found a work around :

i had the customer to the customers list and re-serialize the entire list to the xml document

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(XMLRepository.CustomersPath);
    customers.Add(customer);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, customers);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

is this a good approach , can any one think of a better way ? ( i'm guessing yes) ..

Comment: I would go the serialize/deserialize route in this case. `XmlSerializer` is slow, though, and I wouldn't personally use it as a datastore.

Comment: @JimSchubert are you saying that you wouldn't use an xml document as a datastore ?
or just the xmlserializer ?

Comment: I'm saying I wouldn't use XML for a lot of processing as an alternative to a database. For instance, if you were call `AddCustomer` 200 times, that's **a lot** of file IO and XML serialization performance penalty per call. If you used SQLite3 or SQL Server Compact, performance would most likely be much better. Or, you could deserialize the list, add Customers in memory, and re-serialize.  But here, you'd most likely hit concurrency issues that are handled by the databases.

Comment: that's a much better idea thanks 
i'll just serialize it at the end .